# Dynamically showing content based on user input

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

This is my first knockout.js application so I'm going to simplify my code down a bit to illustrate what I'm trying to accomplish.

I have a view model setup as follows:

```
function Product(data) {
    this.productName = data.productName;
    this.serialNumber = data.serialNumber;
    this.version = ko.observable(data.version);
    this.isSelected = ko.observable(data.IsSelected);
}

function RestoreViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    //Properties
    self.allCustomerProducts = ko.observableArray([]);

    //Computations
    self.selectedProducts = ko.computed(function() {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.allCustomerProducts(), function(product) { return product.isSelected() });
    });
}
```

and some markup setup as follows:

```
<div id="Version1">
   <div class="product1"><a href="">download link goes here.</a></div>
   <div class="product2"><a href="">download link goes here.</a></div>
   <div class="product3"><a href="">download link goes here.</a></div>
</div>

<div id="Version2">
   <div class="product1"><a href="">download link goes here.</a></div>
   <div class="product2"><a href="">download link goes here.</a></div>
   <div class="product3"><a href="">download link goes here.</a></div>
</div>
```

The way this is setup is the user has a list of products that they select, and then for each product they select a version.  This is working as it should, so it can be assumed that the `selectedProducts` computed method is returning a proper array with correct data.

What I haven't been able to figure out after many attempts is how I can show the downloads based on the product and version selection?

If a user selects product1 and version 1 and then also selects product1 and version 2, I need those corresponding elements to appear.

If anything in my view model or if my HTML markup should be different I'm willing to re-work this to make it correct.

**Edit**: Here is an illustration to show what setup and desired output:

[image: Example]

Comment: Check out my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12516575/390278.  You can apply the same concepts to this question.

Comment: @JeffMercado - I could take that approach, but, if you look at my illustration you'll see that the user can actually select a version (environment in the example you linked to) for each product.  This would result in me having to create a computed method for each download section.  Do you have any ideas for how I could make it dynamic?  Alternatively, so I could create one method and have it take in parameters so I don't have to create multiple methods?

Comment: Sure, what you're trying to do seems simple enough.  Would you mind setting up a fiddle to start with?  I'd do it myself but I'm a little busy.

Comment: @JeffMercado - I appreciate your response and time.  Here is a fiddle that I believe portrays what I'm trying to do:  http://jsfiddle.net/Ek0nomik/Sk6Lm/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here ya go: [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeff1203/Sk6Lm/8/)

So the whole plan was to take that array of selected products and create an array of objects that represents the set of downloads for that array.  To get that array, the logic is in the `getSelectedDownloads` function.  Just straight forward grouping by version and mapping.

```js
var getSelectedDownloads = function() {
    var selectedProducts = self.selectedProducts();
    var versions = ko.utils.arrayGetDistinctValues(
        ko.utils.arrayMap(selectedProducts, function (item) { return item.version(); })
    ).sort().reverse();

    return ko.utils.arrayMap(versions, function (version) {
        var items = ko.utils.arrayFilter(selectedProducts, function (item) {
            return item.version() == version;
        }).sort(function (a, b) {
            var x = a.displayName, y = b.displayName;
            return x < y ? -1 : (x > y ? 1 : 0);
        });
        return {
            verid: version.replace(/\./g, ''),
            header: version.replace(/(\d).*/, 'Version $1 Downloads'),
            items: ko.utils.arrayMap(items, function (item) {
                return {
                    label: item.displayName + ' Software',
                    url: '#' //set your urls here
                };
            })
        };
    });
};
```

So each object will contain `verid`, `header` and `items` properties (where the items represents the links) which you could then bind to.

```html
<div id="downloads" data-bind="foreach: selectedDownloads">
    <div data-bind="attr: { id: verid }">
        <h5 data-bind="text: header"></h5>
        <ul data-bind="foreach: items">
            <li>
                <a data-bind="text: label, attr: { href: url }"></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```