# Knockout issue displaying content based on dropdown value

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, typescript

## I just created a jsfiddle so that u can do quick edits
[JSFIDDLE Link to Code](http://jsfiddle.net/jvelezc/BJhQz/11/)

As you can see the `Array` `selectedChoice` works fine in the dropdown and displays content based on the dropdown selected value.

However, when I try to use a `CountryModel` with properties id and name it is trowing errors in Internet Explorer but not in Firefox. however, is odd that the default behavior is not to hide the content   `<p>This content appear when US is selected</p>`

### I suspect this code

```
    <section data-bind="visible: selectedChoiceWithModel().name==='US'">
```

I also tried this

```
<section data-bind="if: selectedChoiceWithModel().name === 'Russia', 
     hasfocus: selectedChoiceWithModel().name === 'Russia'">
    <p>This content appear when Russia is selected</p>
```

Two issues:

[image]

Typescript code

```
class CountryModel {
    id: number;
    name: string;

}
```

compiles to

```
var CountryModel = (function () {
    function CountryModel() {
    }
    return CountryModel;
})();
```

Typescript Code
/// 
/// 
///

```
class ViewModel {
    constructor()
    {
        //initialize the data for the model now this has two purposes. Consider separating the model from its data generation. 
        var x = new CountryModel();
        x.id = 1;
        x.name = "Russia";
        var y = new CountryModel();
        y.id = 2;
        y.name = "US";
        this.countries.push(x);
        this.countries.push(y);
    }

    availableDrugs = ['A', 'B', 'others'];
    firstName: KnockoutObservable<string>  = ko.observable();
    isVisible: KnockoutObservable<boolean> = ko.observable(true); 
    selectedChoice = ko.observable();
    selectedChoiceWithModel = ko.observable();
    countries: KnockoutObservableArray<CountryModel> = ko.observableArray([]);
    sendMe = function () {

        alert(ko.toJSON({ selectedCountryId: this.selectedChoice() }));
    };
}


$(() => {
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(), document.getElementById("model"));
});
```

Compiles to

```
/// <reference path="CountryModel.ts" />
/// <reference path="../Scripts/typings/knockout/knockout.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../Scripts/typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />
var ViewModel = (function () {
    function ViewModel() {
        this.availableDrugs = ['A', 'B', 'others'];
        this.firstName = ko.observable();
        this.isVisible = ko.observable(true);
        this.selectedChoice = ko.observable();
        this.selectedChoiceWithModel = ko.observable();
        this.countries = ko.observableArray([]);
        this.sendMe = function () {
            alert(ko.toJSON({ selectedCountryId: this.selectedChoice() }));
        };
        //initialize the data for the model now this has two purposes. Consider separating the model from its data generation.
        var x = new CountryModel();
        x.id = 1;
        x.name = "Russia";
        var y = new CountryModel();
        y.id = 2;
        y.name = "US";
        this.countries.push(x);
        this.countries.push(y);
    }
    return ViewModel;
})();

$(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(), document.getElementById("model"));
});
```

Html code

```
<!--http://jsfiddle.net/pkysylevych/dqUAz/2/
    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12516123/use-knockout-to-hide-display-questions-based-on-selected-value-in-drop-down
    http://jsbin.com/egacil/2/edit
    http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/342244/Knockout-that-cascading-dropdown

    -->
@section scripts
{
    <script src="~/js/RequestFormModel.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/CountryModel.js"></script>
}
<div id="model">

<p>First name: <strong data-bind="text: firstName"></strong></p>


<p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName" /></p>

   <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isVisible"/>
   <div data-bind="if: isVisible">Hide this content.</div>

        <!--Display content usign observable array--> 
    <select data-bind="options: availableDrugs, value: selectedChoice, optionsCaption: 'choose..'"></select> 
      <input type="text" data-bind="value: firstName, visible: selectedChoice() === 'others', hasfocus: selectedChoice() === 'others'" /> 


    <section data-bind="visible: selectedChoice() === 'A', hasfocus: selectedChoice() === 'A'">
        <p> This content appear when a is selected</p>

    </section>
    <section data-bind="visible: selectedChoice() === 'B', hasfocus: selectedChoice() === 'B'">
        <p>This content appear when B is selected</p>
    </section>




    <!---Sample number two with models instead of just an array --> 
      <select data-bind="options: countries, optionsText: 'name', value: selectedChoiceWithModel, optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>



            <section data-bind="visible: selectedChoiceWithModel().name==='US'">
            <p>This content appear when US is selected</p>
    </section>


</div>
```

Comment: Can you show your hasfocus custom binding?

Comment: custom ??? is straight from knockout http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/hasfocus-binding.html. Anyways I have posted all the code already. I will do a jsfiddle in a second.

Comment: :). That is the hasFocus binding where your sample shows a hasfocus binding.  Note the camelCase.  Copy paste error or mistake in code?

Comment: Up vote because he was able to include a link in the title somehow that's awesome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I really appreciate everyone's help. You did help me identify some of the issues with the code. I have completed the code and here is the result for future people that will probably undergo the same pain as me. i do want to point out that selectedModelWirhChoice().name() was the wrong approach. Instead the key was to put optionsValue: 'name' so that selectedChoiceWithModel() would bind to the property name. Of course one could have also chosen to do the following 
 optionsValue: 'id' to bind to the id number.

## [JsFiddle Code for your convenience](http://jsfiddle.net/BJhQz/15/)

I have included the complete JSFiddle for your convenience but unfortunately I it will show the compiled JavaScript instead of the clean Typescript code. In any case the typescript code is below...

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="~/js/RequestFormModel.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/CountryModel.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="model">

<p>First name: <strong data-bind="text: firstName"></strong></p>


<p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName" /></p>

   <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isVisible"/>
   <div data-bind="if: isVisible">Hide this content.</div>

        <!--Display content usign observable array--> 
    <select data-bind="options: availableDrugs, value: selectedChoice, optionsCaption: 'choose..'"></select> 
      <input type="text" data-bind="value: firstName, visible: selectedChoice() === 'others', hasFocus: selectedChoice() === 'others'" /> 


    <section data-bind="visible: selectedChoice() === 'A', hasFocus: selectedChoice() === 'A'">
        <p> This content appear when a is selected</p>

    </section>
    <section data-bind="visible: selectedChoice() === 'B', hasFocus: selectedChoice() === 'B'">
        <p>This content appear when B is selected</p>
    </section>




    <!---Sample number two with models instead of just an array --> 
      <select data-bind="options: countries, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'name', value: selectedChoiceWithModel, optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>



        <span data-bind="text: selectedChoiceWithModel() ? selectedChoiceWithModel() : 'This content is displayed when the value is unknown'"></span>.


     <span data-bind="if:selectedChoiceWithModel()==='Russia'">Content is displayed when Russia is selected</span>
         <span data-bind="if: selectedChoiceWithModel() === 'US'">Content is displayed when US is selected</span>
</div>




 <h1>Keep in mind i used typescript to generate the javascript</h1>

</body>
</html>
class CountryModel {

    public id: number;
    public name: string;

}


/// <reference path="CountryModel.ts" />
/// <reference path="../Scripts/typings/knockout/knockout.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../Scripts/typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />

class ViewModel {
    constructor()
    {
        //initialize the data for the model now this has two purposes. Consider separating the model from its data generation. 
        var x = new CountryModel();
        x.id = 1;
        x.name = "Russia";
        var y = new CountryModel();
        y.id = 2;
        y.name = "US";
        this.countries.push(x);
        this.countries.push(y);

    }

    availableDrugs = ['A', 'B', 'others'];
    firstName: KnockoutObservable<string>  = ko.observable();
    isVisible: KnockoutObservable<boolean> = ko.observable(true); 
    selectedChoice = ko.observable();
    selectedChoiceWithModel = ko.observable();
    countries: KnockoutObservableArray<CountryModel> = ko.observableArray([]);
    sendMe = function () {

        alert(ko.toJSON({ selectedCountryId: this.selectedChoice() }));
    };
}


$(() => {
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(), document.getElementById("model"));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your binding is breaking in ie and not in other better browsers because of a case error that ie can't handle.

The hasFocus binding is camelCase so try converting all your hasfocus bindings to hasFocus.

**Edit**

Alright, your problem was more than one -

http://jsfiddle.net/BJhQz/14/

You need to make sure that selectedChoiceWithModel is defined before you try to bind to properties on it.  I added a containerless binding to your view to keep from trying to see the name of it if it was not yet selected.

Next, I made a few updates to your view model to make it easier to understand for me.  I am not saying they are required, but without them your view model was suffering from my inability to read it.

StackOverflow.com wants some code so here it is -

```
<!-- ko if: selectedChoiceWithModel() -->
    <section data-bind="visible: $data.selectedChoiceWithModel().name() === 'Russia'">
        <p>This content appear when Russia is selected</p>
    </section>
    <h1 data-bind="text: selectedChoiceWithModel().name()"></h1>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: k i updated the hasfocus to hasFocus on the js fiddle. Still some issues.

Comment: The second issue is it should be selectedModelWirhChoice().name() === 'US' not selectedModelWithChoice().name.  Remember that knockout unwraps observables when directly evaluating but when you are using them in a conditional way we need to get their value.

Comment: k i fixed both things u mentioned http://jsfiddle.net/jvelezc/BJhQz/11/ and still running into something not making it work.  Could it be that options: countries contains to CountryModels items? Is that proper?

Comment: By the way I appreciate your help so far.

Comment: Of course, I think the problem in your fiddle is that you are using if as a binding instead conditionally.  I am going to update it and repaste it back here.

Comment: Alright, looking at the fiddle you create a CountryModel but what are you trying to do with it?  I am going to update the model to what I think you might want it to be